# C++ - Trying to create a pointer to a pointer within a node (that is pointed to by another node), is this right?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

enum Color { black, red };

struct node {
public:
    int key;
    Color color;
    node *left, *right, *parent;
};

class RBT {
public:
    node nil;
    node *root = new node;
    RBT() {
        nil.color = black;
        root = &nil;
    }

    void left_rotate(node *x) {
        node *y = x->right;
        if (y->left == &nil) {}
    }
};

int main()
{
    RBT t;
    cout << "t color is: " << t.root->color;
}
```

Basically I'm trying to code a Red-Black Tree data structure but I am still very confused about pointing to pointers within class objects.

The rotate function is going to be used in future functions, and right now can't really be used. But there's no point continuing on and writing more code when the code I already have is just not working.

Another important bit: all nodes that don't have another node to point to will point to the "nil" member of the tree. So that's what I'm trying to test for in the function, but I don't think it's done right.

Comment: And if I wanted x.right to point to y.left, how would I do that?

Comment: *But there's no point continuing on and writing more code when the code I already have is just not working.* Exactly! You might be amazed by the number of people who plow forward and wind up debugging code they never should have written in the first place for hours before discarding it.

Comment: @user4581301 - It's become a kind of weard habit for me that I pretty much compile every 10-20 lines at the most. I still have nightmares from staying up until 3-4 AM on school nights trying to fix code that I wrote all in one sitting without testing in between.

Comment: Not even close to weird. That's recommended behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
enum class Color { black, red };

struct node {
    static node nil;  // so nil can be used in the constructor of node

    int key;
    Color color;
    node *parent;
    node *left;
    node *right;

    // Use this constructor for new nodes. Parameters you don't provide
    // have defaults.
    node(int key = 0, Color color = Color::black,
         node *parent = &nil, node *left = &nil, node *right = &nil)
    : key{ key }, color{ color }, parent{ parent }, left{ left }, right{ right }
    {}
};

node node::nil;

struct RBT {
    node root;  // please, no new without purpose

    void left_rotate(node *x) {
        node *y = x->right;
        if (y->left == &node::nil) {
            // whatever
        }
    }
};
```

You might want to look up `std::unique_ptr<>` and `std::shared_ptr<>`

Also,

> ```
> cout << "t color is: " << t.root->color;
> ```

Won't work without writing an `operator<<` which takes a `std::ostream&` and a `Color`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, Color const &color)
{
    if(color == Color::black)
        return os << "black";
    return os << "red";
}
```

Comment: @Swordfish - Thanks!

It's little things like adding
    `node *parent = &nil`
That help most for me. Dealing with simple pointers are easy for me, but when you start combining it with classes and structs that have pointer members that point to more pointer members ... it just gets confusing

I'll leave `std::unique_ptr<>` for another time because I have enough of a problem understanding what I have here, but I will definitely make sure to check it out later